# Error trying to archive a Xamarin Android app that uses WindowsAzure.Storage 7.2.1

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, azure-storage

I am unable to archive a Xamarin Android app that uses WindowsAzure.Storage 7.2.1. I am doing everything in Visual Studio. Building, running, debugging and everything is working fine, including accessing resources in the cloud in Azure blob storage.

However so far I cannot get archiving/packaging a Release build to work. It apparently fails on this compile warning "Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly", though the pane that shows archive errors is not resizable and is only 3 lines high and clips the majority of the output. It says "The archiving process has failed. Please see the Errors section for more details." The little bit of output that Errors section shows matches that same "Found conflicts..." compile warning.

The first instance of that warning in the build output is this one, but there are around 20 of these for lots of assemblies:
Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "4.0.0.0" [] to Version "4.2.0.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll]

The warning that Visual Studio shows says that I can double-click the warning to add binding redirects, so I tried that and that did not resolve the issue (and doesn't resolve the build warnings either).

I have these things installed: Visual Studio 2015, Xamarin 4.2.0.719, Xamarin.Android 7.0.1.6, Android 7.0 (API 24) SDK Platform

A newer Android SDK is available (7.1.1 (API 25)) but Visual Studio/Xamarin doesn't seem to recognize it and so I can't select it so I am using 7.0 (API 24), and when I modify TargetFrameworkVersion in the .csproj manually something reverts it back to v7.0. I just downloaded the Xamarin Installer yesterday so presumably have the latest version of that.

I was able to archive a Debug build despite having the same warnings, however when I tried to install on my Android phone it complained that the package was corrupt. Anyway I assume I should be archiving and deploying a Release build.

How can I archive/package my Xamarin Android app that uses WindowsAzure.Storage?

Comment: From my experence, it maybe multiple projects reference the same assembly (e.g. System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms) but the multiple projects require different versions.Please have a try to right click the **solution** -> **Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...**, then  set all of the projects that use the same version of the assembly. Hope it is useful.

Comment: I rewrote/ported my app to Java using Android Studio and have no problem deploying now, of course. The apk is now 1.6 MB instead of 60 MB as well.